Explaining (\\b\\S+)( \\1\\b)+" in detecting consecutive duplicate words for Java
In this Remove consecutive duplicate words, we would take
"alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta"
as a input string,  and output.
"alpha beta gamma delta alpha beta gamma delta"
One of the solution I saw was. very elegant but I still struggle with the regex
public class Kata {
    public static String removeConsecutiveDuplicates(String s){
           return s.replaceAll("(\\b\\S+)( \\1\\b)+", "$1");
    }
}

\\b means the word boundary.  \\s+ means. one or more empty spaces.
( \\1) means the first group ie (\\b\\S+) 
.  ( \\1\\b)+  means matching first group and a duplicate word, correct?  I am sure what the empty space in ( \\1\\b)+ does actually.
I didn't try anything.

yes...\\s+ means one or more white-space characters (short for [ \t\n\x0b\r\f]) but, the \\S+ (uppercase S) as you show in your regex means one or more non-whitespace characters.


If you have one additional space in between the words, that pattern fails.
I'd instead use this pattern: (\\b\\S+\\b(?:\\s*))(?:\\s*\\1){1,} or simply \\b(\\S+)(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+. (See the comment).

Details

\\b: a word boundary.
\\S+: means one or more non-whitespace.
(?:\\s*\\1){1,}: non-capture group including back-reference to group 1, repeated one or more times (i.e., {1,}).

Code
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(\\b\\S+\\b(?:\\s*))(?:\\s*\\1){1,}";
        final String string = "gamma gamma gamma   gamma alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma   gamma delta delta";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));

            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}

Prints
Full match: gamma gamma gamma   gamma 
Group 1: gamma 
Full match: beta beta 
Group 1: beta 
Full match: gamma gamma gamma 
Group 1: gamma 
Full match: beta beta 
Group 1: beta 
Full match: gamma gamma   gamma 
Group 1: gamma 
Full match: delta delta
Group 1: delta


Comment:
@bobble bubble: The non-capture group around \b does not look necessary. I think you can further simplify your idea to \b(\S+)(?:\s+\1\b)+.

The non-capture group around \b does not look necessary. I think you can further simplify your idea to \b(\S+)(?:\s+\1\b)+

@bobblebubble You're right. My bad! I was adding something in there. Then, forgot to remove the non-capture group... Thanks! I actually use {1,} instead of '+', to create variety since the question was about "explaining".
